# ListStreamPlot can't present closed curve with StreamStyle -> "Line"

Tags: plotting, graphics

I try this code to plot streamline

```
data = Table[{{x, y}, {-y, x}}, {x, -2, 2, 1/200}, {y, -2, 2, 1/200}];
ListStreamPlot[data, StreamStyle -> "Line", StreamPoints -> 4]
```

It returns
[image]

**Question:** In the picture, the lines are not closed in the red circles.

So, how to get closed curves use parameters of `ListStreamPlot`?
Thank you!

Comment: Might be hard to get to be done automatically, given that numerics usually won't give exactly closed curves, esp. with discrete data. -- I mean, with the discrete data, one has to assume how the vector field is to be estimated/interpolated. How do you know the resulting vector field has closed curves?  Any perturbation of `{-y, x}` tends to destroy the closed curves.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I know that the data I want to plot has closed streamline from its physical meaning, so I want to get closed curves within MMA. In my question, I just present an example. How to get closed curves with some additional process? Thank you!

Comment: A hack: `ListStreamPlot[data, StreamStyle -> "Line", StreamPoints -> 4] /. 
 Line[{a_, b__}] :> Line[{a, b, a}]` but it doesn't look good for the reason Michael gives.

Comment: Can you estimate a potential function or some invariant for the field? You could use it to draw level curves, which would approximate the closed orbits.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I cannot get potential function. I only have velocity vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I had in mind for estimating a potential function:

```
grad = MapAt[{-#[[2]], #[[1]]} &, data, {All, All, 2}];
pot = Accumulate@grad[[All, All, 2, 1]] + Accumulate /@ grad[[All, All, 2, 2]];

ListContourPlot[pot, DataRange -> {{-2., 2.}, {-2., 2.}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The potential function could be multiplied by `Δx Δy`, but there's no real need to do it for the plot.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListStreamPlot[data, StreamStyle -> "Line", StreamPoints -> 4] /. 
 Line -> (BSplineCurve[#, SplineClosed -> True] &)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]